# Keep getting an error saying "The data could not be read" because of format

Tags: json, swift

Essentially I am creating a login view controller in my swift app that verifies and logs in a user.

This is how the app is requesting and going through with the POST HTTP Request:

```
import Foundation

enum MyResult<T, E: Error> {

    case success(T)
    case failure(E)
}

class NetworkingService {

    let baseUrl = "https://example/example/login.php"

    func handleResponse(for request: URLRequest,
                        completion: @escaping (Result<User, Error>) -> Void) {

        let session = URLSession.shared

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                guard let unwrappedResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
                    completion(.failure(NetworkingError.badResponse))
                    return
                }

                print(unwrappedResponse.statusCode)

                switch unwrappedResponse.statusCode {

                case 200 ..< 300:
                    print("success")

                default:
                    print("failure")
                }

                if let unwrappedError = error {
                    completion(.failure(unwrappedError))
                    return
                }

                if let unwrappedData = data {

                    do {
                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: unwrappedData, options: [])
                        print(json)

                        if let user = try? JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: unwrappedData) {
                            completion(.success(user))

                        } else {
                            let errorResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(ErrorResponse.self, from: unwrappedData)
                            completion(.failure(errorResponse))
                        }

                    } catch {
                        completion(.failure(error))
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        task.resume()
    }

    func request(endpoint: String,
                 parameters: [String: Any],
                 completion: @escaping (Result<User, Error>) -> Void) {

        guard let url = URL(string: baseUrl + endpoint) else {
            completion(.failure(NetworkingError.badUrl))
            return
        }

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)

        var components = URLComponents()

        var queryItems = [URLQueryItem]()

        for (key, value) in parameters {

            let queryItem = URLQueryItem(name: key, value: String(describing: value))
            queryItems.append(queryItem)
        }

        components.queryItems = queryItems


        let queryItemData = components.query?.data(using: .utf8)

        request.httpBody = queryItemData
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        handleResponse(for: request, completion: completion)
    }

    func request(endpoint: String,
                 loginObject: Login,
                 completion: @escaping (Result<User, Error>) -> Void) {

        guard let url = URL(string: baseUrl + endpoint) else {
            completion(.failure(NetworkingError.badUrl))
            return
        }

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)

        do {
            let loginData = try JSONEncoder().encode(loginObject)
            request.httpBody = loginData

        } catch {
            completion(.failure(NetworkingError.badEncoding))
        }

        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        handleResponse(for: request, completion: completion)
    }


}

enum NetworkingError: Error {
    case badUrl
    case badResponse
    case badEncoding
}
```

This is how the structure looks like:

```
import UIKit

struct User: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let username: String
}
```

Because I am working with a mySQL database I am using php script to produce JSON that takes parameters from input.

This is what the JSON looks like:

```
[
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "KevinName",
        "username": "kName"
    }
]
```

The status code returns success 200 but no data is loaded into the app and I get the error

> The data couldn't be read because it isn't in the correct format

I believe it has something to do with the PHP script that creates the JSON

```
<?php


$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// This SQL statement selects ALL from the table 'Equipment'

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "SELECT id, driver_name, username FROM table1 WHERE (username = '$username') and password = '$password' ";


if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{
    // Create temporary connection
    $resultArray = array();
    $tempArray = array();

    // Look through each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {

        $tempArray = $row;
        array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
    }


    echo json_encode($resultArray);
}

mysqli_close($con);



?>
```

Comment: there may b some warning in return data.

Comment: I used Postman to fetch a user by providing a username and password and it worked perfectly

Comment: In all of your `catch` blocks, add `print(error)` so you can see the actual problem.

Comment: see in postman preview tab. if any warning or error you can see in taht tab.

Comment: From the response, you need to use `[User].self` instead of `User.self` in this line `try? JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: unwrappedData)`

Comment: One error is pretty clear, look at the JSON: The value for key `id` is `String`. Everything in double quotes is `String` even `"123"` or `"false"`, there is no exception.